# Samba Active Directory Domain Controller not working

Tags: debian, samba, active-directory

I have installed the current samba (via apt-get) on Debian (Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u5) and am configuring it to be an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD-DC).

I've also got it configured to use LDAP for the password back-end, but that doesn't seem to matter - I get the same error either way.

I am having trouble getting a Windows 10 VM to join the domain.  After some digging, I have narrowed it down.  I can run this command

`net use \\dc1\ipc$ /u:MYDOMAIN\Administrator password_goes_here`

and I see this error in the log.smbd:

```
[2018/01/24 22:10:08.073191,  3] ../source3/lib/util_procid.c:54(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
```

It would be *really* nice if the error message would say *what* file or directory, but it doesn't.  I looked at the code by browsing the git repository and this appears to be trying to open a lock file of some kind.  It looks like this file *should* be `/var/run/samba/msg.lock/####` where the #### is the PID of the process.  I can see that there are files in that directory and there's one file for each instance of samba that's running.  I even tried making the files writable by all (temporarily).

I'm baffled at this point.

One site I found by googling the error message had a bunch of "me too" responses of other people with the same problem.  One reply suggested setting `ntlm auth = yes` which didn't help.